# Replacing array variables in string with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use RegEx to replace an arrays value in a string that I have created.

For example:

```
$params = array(1 => 'butter', 2 => 'yellow', 3 => 'good', 4 => 'low-fat');
$query = 'type=$params[1]&color=$params[2]&taste=$params[3]&content=$params[4]';
```

I wanted to use `preg_replace` to replace all of the `$params` in the `$query` with the actual values for the string.

I had originally attempted:

```
$query = preg_replace("(\$params\[[1-9]+[0-9]*\])",$query,$params);
```

But that seemed to create an array for $query.

I was hoping to get:

```
$query =  'type=butter&color=yellow&taste=good&content=low-fat';
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: While the design is overall wrong, your preg_replace call has the parameters in the wrong order. The third parameter is the original string that you are manipulating.

Comment: To do a replacement for a key/value, I think you have to capture the key, and use it to reference the replacement value.  `\$params\[([1-9]+[0-9]*)\]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `preg_replace_callback` for this:

```
$val = preg_replace_callback('/\$params\[(\d+)\]/', function ($m) use ($params)
      { return $params[$m[1]]; }, $query);
//=> type=butter&color=yellow&taste=good&content=low-fat
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you explain the difference between `/\$params\[(\d+)\]/` and my original `(\$params\[[1-9]+[0-9]*\])`?

Comment: You regex is capturing `$params[1]` where mine is just capturing `1`. We just need number to get the indexed value from array `params`

Answer (score 0):

why not do something like this?

```
$params = array(
    'type' => 'butter',
    'color' => 'yellow',
    'taste' => 'good',
    'content' => 'low-fat'
);
$query = http_build_query($params);
```

Comment: I was attempting to use a predefined format in a string. I wanted to match the paramaters passed from the URL to that string, to create my variables.